# xml rendering in html

Tags: html, css, xml, xhtml

I have the foll xml can anyone please guide me how can i render it in html table.

```
<order po="123" contact="me" comment="out of stock reorder">
   <shippingAddress line1="123 Fake St" city="Madison" state="WI" zip="12345" />
   <lineItem id="1" quantity="50" comment="for me">
      <part number="XYZ123" descr="Spark Plug" price="5.00" weight="0.12" />
   </lineItem>
   <lineItem id="2" quantity="1">
      <part number="ABC456" descr="Jacket" price="150.00" weight="5.0" />
   </lineItem>
</order>
```

Comment: @user443946: If you want an XSLT example, please provide desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XSLT:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score 1):

XSLT, if you want to style it and use is as xml

JavaScript if you want/need it parsed on the client side

A serverside language if you want it parsed on the server

Your question is vague. Please detail.